# What is wrong with my doGet function?

Tags: google-apps-script, querystringparameter

I have been going thru every single thread in here that might have remotely even helped a little, but I can't still get it to work.

I'm currently helping my company explore a little queryString scripting but now I'm stuck. I have a link that goes `...../exec?id=8845`

And this is the function that I'm using.

```
function doGet(e) {


  var student_id = e.Parameter.id;
  Logger.log(student_id);

  //open the spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss_id);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var Setrange = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  Logger.log(ss.getName());
  Logger.log(sheet.getSheetName());
  Logger.log(Setrange);

  if (student_id == "8845") 
  {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h2>Finally something comes</h2>")
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(student_id);


}
```

but what comes out is just this:

```
{"queryString":"id=8845","parameter":{"id":"8845"},"contextPath":"","parameters":{"id":["8845"]},"contentLength":-1}
```

I've been going thru everything for about a week and it's been eating into me! Can any kind soul please help me out with this?

Comment: Can you be more clear -- what is the desired functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're using [Google apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutput(String)), you need to call getContent() to get the actual HTML from HTMLService:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h2>Finally something comes</h2>").getContent();
```